# Using code behind for User Controls or MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

First of all, here is some working code:

In `MyUserControl.xaml` I have set `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` in the `UserControl` block. A little bit further in my code I have

```
<Label Content="{Binding Header}" />
```

I think it's obvious that `Header` is in the code behind file `MyUserControl.xaml.cs` like this: `public string Header { get; set; }`. Beside this property, there is also a function to make the User Control visible:

```
public object Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, string button)
{
    Header = caption;
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    return "test";
}
```

This is working all fine. In my application where I want to use this I add this to my .xaml file names Window.xaml:

```
<t:MessageBox x:Name="nBox"/>
```

This allows me to use this:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    testButton.Content = nBox.Show("1", "1", "1")
End Sub
```

---

**What I'm wondering is, is it a good idea to design User Controls like this? I mean, it gives me the ability to just call `.Show` on my User Control and make it visible and send the required things I need. I tried to implement MVVM but I have the feeling it's unnecessary in this case and will only make the code more complex.**

Comment: MVVM adds separation of layers and enhance loose coupling. where as the approach you've mentioned would increase coupling between UI and the code behind which may be costly in long term maintenance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little more separation:

MainViewModel

```
class MainViewModel : Mvvm.ViewModel
{
    private Alert _pageAlert = null;
    public Alert PageAlert { get { return this._pageAlert; } set { this._pageAlert = value; this.PropertyChange("PageAlert"); } }
    public Mvvm.Command ShowAlert
    {
        get
        {
            return new Mvvm.Command(() =>
            {
                this.PageAlert = new Alert();
                this.PageAlert.Show();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The Alert's View Model

```
public class Alert
{
    private bool _isVisible = false;
    public bool IsVisible { get { return this._isVisible; } set { this._isVisible = value; PropertyChanged("IsVisible"); }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public Uri Image { get; set; } 
    public string ButtonCaption { get; set; }

    #if (DEBUG)
    public Alert()
    {
        this.Header = "Alert";
        this.ButtonCaption = "OK";
        this.Image = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png");
        this.Message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
    }
    #endif
    public Alert(string Header, string Message, string ButtonCaption, Uri Image)
    {
        this.Header = Header;
        this.Message = Message;
        this.ButtonCaption = ButtonCaption;
        this.Image = Image;
    }

    public Mvvm.Command ButtonClick
    {
        get
        {
            return new Mvvm.Command(() =>
            {
                this.IsVisible = false;
            });
        }
    }
    public void Show()
    {
        this.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

The Alert's UserControl

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="StackOverflow.AlertUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:StackOverflow"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:Alert, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">

    <Grid Background="LightGray" Opacity=".95">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="6*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Header-->
        <Rectangle Fill="Navy" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Opacity=".25"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" FontSize="16" />
        <!--Body-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Margin="15" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Message}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14"  Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
        <!--Footer-->
        <Button Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black" Command="{Binding ButtonClick}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ButtonCaption}" Foreground="Black" />
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the sample main page for usage:

```
<Page
        x:Class="StackOverflow.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:StackOverflow"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <local:AlertUserControl Height="300" Width="400" DataContext="{Binding PageAlert}" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}" />
        <Button Content="Show Alert" Command="{Binding ShowAlert}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Some simple implementations of the Mvvm stuff (converters, commands) in case it's needed.

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (bool)(value ?? false) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}


public class Command : ICommand
{
    private Action _commandAction;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _commandAction();
    }
    public Command(Action CommandAction)
    {
        this._commandAction = CommandAction;
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void PropertyChange(string Property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Also, if you're just trying to display a simple alert, in Win8 there's `Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(string content, string title).ShowAsync()`

Comment: The problem is, I place my `User Control` in my MainWindow like this: `<t:MessageBox x:Name="Box" />`. Then in my MainWindowViewModel I want to call `Box.Show();`, but if I'm working with ViewModels, I'm unable to access the `Show()` method.

Comment: Exactly. What I've posted would instead hide or show the message based on a binding to the UserControl's Visibility: using a converter, if the Alert is null, the converter will return `Visibility.Collapsed` else `Visibility.Visible`

Comment: The thing is, I want the Show `Method` to be in de `UserControls` `ViewModel` so whenever I want to use my control, I only have to add it to the MainView and call Show in its ViewModel. My goal is to create a `MessageBox` like `UserControl` but it is inside the same `Window`.

Comment: To clarify, the Show `Method` is inside the `UserControls` code behind. I want to be able to add my UserControl to my MainWindow and call UserControl.Show() in my MainWindow ViewModel. So in your example, the Show should be in the Alert class. Hope this is a better explanation.

Comment: Edited to include a Show() -- the point is that you don't want to set visibility on the UserControl from the ViewModel, but instead have the UserControl's Visibily bound to a public property on the ViewModel (`Alert.IsVisible`)

Comment: I have posted an 'Answer' that I have right now. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Fist Create ViewMOdel class

```
public class ViewModel:ViewModelBase
```

{

```
  public string Header{get;set;} 

}
```

then using this class to xaml.cs constructor

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel= new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }

    public ViewModel viewModel{ get; set; }
```

then work your function as

```
    public object Show(string messageBoxText, string caption, string button)
    {
         viewModel.Header = caption;
         this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        return "test";
     }
```

Comment: So, all the visual stuff is in the code behind file, the logic in the view model?

Comment: Where are you expecting to call Show() from?

Comment: I place my User Control in my MainWindow like this: <t:MessageBox x:Name="Box" />. Then in my MainWindowViewModel I want to call Box.Show();, but if I'm working with ViewModels, I'm unable to access the Show() method.